# pg_ctl: command not found, what package has this command?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed pgadmin using the ubuntu software center and am trying to access a local database (recently downloaded from the internet). I have tried to run the pg_ctl command (running as postgres) however this gives a command not found error.
I have also ran the following commands:

```
echo $PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

so that's a bit of a weird place but still.
`whereis pg_ctl: pg_ctl: /usr/share/man/man1/pg_ctl.1.gz type pg_ctl: -su:` so it's somewhere on my system
 `type: pg_ctl: not found`         which looks wrong

`apt-cache policy postgres-xc` gives me a `No such file or directory` error the output of

`sudo apt-get install postgres-xc` is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgres-xc
```

sudo apt-get -q update gives me :

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [93.6 kB]
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Get:4 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [2,494 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [29.9 kB]
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,797 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [347 kB]
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4,627 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [85.4 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,439 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [366 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [89.5 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,635 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 1,081 kB in 0s (1,561 kB/s)
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list gives me :

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: you can fix using path setup in Linux prompt you can see this post :https://thedbadmin.com/how-to-fix-pg_ctl-command-not-found/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should edit your path:

```
$ cd ~
$ vim .profile
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/{version}/bin
export PATH
$ . ~/.profile
```

Replace `{version}` with the correct version number.

And now you can execute the command from the shell:

```
pg_ctl --help
pg_ctl is a utility to initialize, start, stop, or control a PostgreSQL server.
```

Comment: There's a reason `pg_ctl` for a particular pg version (e.g. 9.1, 9.4) is not in your `$PATH` on Ubuntu. If you upgrade Ubuntu, multiple pg versions may be running, and only `pg_ctlcluster` will take care of **all** of them. See [@PeterEisentraut](http://askubuntu.com/users/1156/peter-eisentraut)'s more canonical [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/385970/31658).

Answer (score 54):

You shouldn't run `pg_ctl` directly under Ubuntu/Debian.  Use `pg_ctlcluster` instead, which is installed by `postgresql-common`. See the documentation [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-common).

Comment: If you don't which `version` and `cluster` parameters you should use when calling `pg_ctlcluster`, check the output of `pg_lsclusters`.

Comment: hey Peter ,  legit question , why not running `pg_ctl` directly?

Comment: The default `cluster` is `main` so just use `sudo pg_ctlcluster <version> main <command>`

Comment: @Hari Reddy how do I run `pg_ctl logrotate` then? It doesn't seem to be available with `pg_ctlcluster`

Answer (score 10):

use this code:

```bash
sudo pg_ctlcluster 'cluster_version' 'cluster-name' 'action'
```

where:

```bash
/etc/postgresql/<cluster-version>/<cluster-name>/start.conf
```

where action:

```bash
start|stop|restart|reload|status|promote
```

example my code:

```bash
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

```bash
$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main reload
```

Comment: pg_lsclusters is also useful to find out cluster-version and cluster-name.